# AWS-sdk contributes to Build Error "Uncaught TypeError: e is not a constructor"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My react application is working fine until I wanted to wrap it up and deploy it. The build via `vite build` is successful. However, when the built folder "dist" is deployed and served, it says `Uncaught TypeError: e is not a constructor`.

After hours of debug, I can confirm that it's the aws-sdk that is causing the issue. In particular, the following code:

```js
const s3 = new S3({
  accessKeyId: VITE_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: VITE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: VITE_REGION,
});
```

I think the `new S3(...config)` here corresponds to a line that reads `o = new e;` in the compiled *index.bad38efb.js* file that gives the `Uncaught TypeError: e is not a constructor` error.

Ultimately the question comes down to, is there any alternative that I could authenticate with s3 or does anyone know how to resolve this problem? Please let me know what extra information could I provide to answer the question.

Comment: I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, although harder to debug since I was not getting any errors in building.

Solution is to move to the [v3 version of the SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html) which is better maintained (and has other benefits too).